# How to move text to the top edge of its parent div

Tags: css

I'm trying to have text inside a `<div>` touch the top of its border without using any "hacked" solution should as `position: absolute`, etc.

I've tried adding 0px to its padding and margin, but I can't seem to figure it out. Is there an easy solution that I haven't thought of?

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 50px; width: 100%;">
  <span>This text should touch the top of the red line</span>
</div>
```

I thought adding the 0px to the margin and padding would do something, but nothing has changed.

Comment: add characters like `ÂË` and you will see that you will touch the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the text doesn't touch the border of the div is that the characters inside the span have their own "padding" in the form of the `line-height` attribute.

If you add a border to the span, you will see that the two borders do overlap...

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 50px; width: 100%; ">
  <span style="border: 1px solid blue;">This text should touch the top of the red line</span>
</div>
```

To remove the gap between the characters in the span and the border of the div, you would need to adjust the line height of the div...

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 50px; width: 100%; line-height: 0.8em; ">
  <span>This text should touch the top of the red line</span>
</div>
```

The other solution is to use absolute positioning of the span. Though I'm not sure why you have an aversion to that technique.

Answer (score -1):

`position: absolute;` is not a "hacked" solution. Absolute positioning is set in relation to the closest relatively positioned element. So if your div is positioned relatively and your span is positioned absolutely, then your span will be positioned always in relation to your div.

Alternatively, if you just don't like the little space that naturally appears above the text and you want it to be very flushed, simply just set a `line-height` on your span.